# How to automatically merge Texas survey block data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have Data from the Texas rail road commission.  I'm trying to get the block data to display with a thick line.  The problem is the data is in surveys.  I exported a copy of the shapefile.  If you take a look at the L2BLOCK colunm you see that I started merging them together, but it take forever if you have to do so for a lot of counties.

[image]

I want the blocks to have a thicker line to seperate them from the surveys.  Here's what the table above looks like.

[image]

You can see that some of them are merged and some not.  Is there way to automate merges based on a same block numbers in the attribute table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use the [Dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000) tool based on the L2BLOCK field.

Unless I'm misunderstanding.